# not a dictionary of a list, but a dictionary of a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Because it's a dictionary of dictionaries that the function has to return, not a list of dictionaries,

I have trouble with put a dictionary within an empty dictionary. Since it's a nested dictionary,

appending wouldn't work since it's not a list of dictionaries.

Can you guys please pinpoint where the error is?

This is my code.

```
def run():
    name_dict = ['Product', 'Brand', 'Cost']
    product = {}
    while True:
        item = {}
            for key in name_dict:
            input_item = input("Enter {}: ".format(key))
            if input_item == 'quit':
                return product
            
            item[key] = input_item
        
        
        print()



product = run()

print(product)
```

This is the question.

Comment: I don't see anything returning here. Can you explain which function should return what exactly?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: This is the expected result  { 1: {'Product': 'Milk', 'Brand': 'Anchor', 'Cost': '4.90'},
 2: {'Product': 'Bread', 'Brand': 'Vogel', 'Cost': '3.80'} }

Answer (score 0):

You forget to update `product` with `item`. Put this line after `item[key] = input_item`:

```
product[str(item['Product'])] = item
```

This adds item to the product dictionary. As key I used the users input for the Product name. str() in case the user only uses digits to name a product.